# how load the so in the depends modle library

Tags: android, android-studio

i migrate the project in eclipse into android studio struct.and the same code, the app run could not find the so lib which included in the depends model library.the model library i dependsed by the app.
the error log in the follow

```
Java_com_alibaba_mobileim_channel_service_InetIO_nGetInetMode__)
05-10 14:27:41.521 28276-28276/xxxxxxxxxxxx(package name) E/InetIO: java_nGetInetMode
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.alibaba.mobileim.channel.service.InetIO.nGetInetMode() (tried Java_com_alibaba_mobileim_channel_service_InetIO_nGetInetMode and Java_com_alibaba_mobileim_channel_service_InetIO_nGetInetMode__)
        at com.alibaba.mobileim.channel.service.InetIO.nGetInetMode(Native Method)
```

who can tell me load the so in the depends model library